# Let's say the random code is ['G', 'B', 'B', 'G'] and the guess is ['G', 'G', 'B', 'B'] so the hint supposed to be '1100' but it only display '11'

Tags: python

```
    codePosition = ' '
    codeColours = ' '
    for code in range (4):
        if correctPosition == '0':
            correctColour == '1'
        if correctColour == 1 and correctPosition == 0:
            codeColours += 1
    print(codePosition + codeColours , '\n')        
    return codePosition, codeColours
```

1. Let's say the random code is ['G', 'B', 'B', 'G'] and the guess is ['G', 'G', 'B', 'B'] so the hint supposed to be '1100' but it only display '11'. I have tried various method to solve the problem but it doesn't work. 0 indicates the correct colour but is not in the position while 1 indicates correct in both colour and position.

Comment: Posting your full program will be helpful for those trying to help. It seems like there's more to this. Also including the full context of the question will make the objective more clear. I'm assuming the user is trying to guess a 4 digit code with limited attempts. Maybe include something like that in the problem description.

Comment: in the second for loop, the elif block fires, but you haven't reset the codeposition to ' ' so the if portion never executes.

Comment: the first attempt yields code = 1, userinput = 1, so userGuess[1]  is G and compCode[1] is G, and 1 = 1, so codePosition is now '1'...  after that codePosition is never set to ' ' again...  codePosition == ' ' and compCode[code] in userGuess is never true.

Comment: the 3rd pass of the first for loop, and the 3rd pass of the second for loop yeild: code = 3, userinput = 3, so userGuess[3] is B and compCode[3] is B, and 3=3 --> codePosition is now set to '11' --> this is the result you are getting.  reset codePosition to ' ' between the for loops.

Comment: I think the objective is to make a guess at the code, then have the result be color coded and sorted based on the accuracy of the guess. My guess is this is a mastermind clone. It's unclear what the requirements are here based on the expected output. OP, could you include the full requirements of the task? Until then we can only speculate on how to help.

Comment: are there only 2 possible colors?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think your output must be an ordered set of characters -- I've tried to reason this through and either the output is allowed to be of any length from 0 to 16 or the out put must be 4 ordered characters.  I think your initial question has a serious flaw and you need to rewrite it.

Comment: regarding your edit: if userGuess[userInput] == compCode[code] then compCode[code] in userGuess is always true.  you might as well write: elif userGuess[userInput] == compCode[code] and code != userInput:  it has exactly the same effect.  but as i already pointed out this will result in a variable length hint.

Comment: if you want to limit the hint to length 4 and/or ensure the 1's come first in your hint then you need to keep track of the indices of both correct color and position to exclude them from further processing.

Comment: is the hint restricted to length 4?   should [b,b,b,b] and [g,g,g,g] output 0000 or ' '?

Comment: are you sure that you want [g,b,b,g] and [g,g b,b] to output 1100 and not 1010?

Comment: should 0's mark that the color is matched to at least one index in which the userGuess at that index is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to output a code that marks the number of times the position and color match, without necessarily marking exactly where it matches -- I'm not sure of that, but you indicate the hint should be 1100 and not 1010 given [g,b,b,g] and [g,g,b,b].

If I understand what you are trying to do:

```
if userGuess != compCode:
   if attempts > 0 and attempts < maxAttempts and len(userGuess) == 4:
       codePosition = ' '
       wrongCounter = 0
       for code in range (4):
           for userInput in range (4):
               if code == userInput:
                   if userGuess[userInput] == compCode[code]:
                       codePosition += '1'
                   else:
                    wrongCounter += 1
        for wrongColorInPosition in range (wrongCounter):
            codePosition += '0'
        print (codePosition, '/n')
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer was meant as guidance rather than a solution on what looks like a homework question. I've commented on the users question to ask them to include more information as the information in the question is not complete to adequately solve their problem.

Since you're learning I'd rather not solve the problems for you, but give you some tools to make it easier.

1. Try using a while loop that checks the current users attempt count against the attempt limit.

   ```
   MAX_ATTEMPTS = 4
   attempt = 0
   while attempt > MAX_ATTEMPTS: 
       attempt += 1
       # process user guess here
   ```
2. Your code and guess are lists. Look into the built-in zip method https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip to pair the two lists and compare them.

   ```
    zip(userGuess, compCode)
   ```

will output something like:

```
[('G', 'G'), ('B', 'G'), ('B', 'B'), ('G', 'B')]
```

You can then quickly compare the pairs.

Hopefully these suggestions help you.

Comment: This does not solve OP's question at all, Since his problem is clearly with how he's dealing with comparing the guessed values against the answers, he does not have the algorithm to do that rather than the syntax. By having a list of tuple of position, it still does not provide a clear direction on how to find the number of correct color and the number of correct color with matching position. I suggest you update your answer with that.